# Which editor creates file with extension html.add

Tags: html, text-editor

My sister teaches HTML language on the university. Students have to build their own website during class but one of them gave the project with weird code which cannot be written by hand. Moreover each HTML file has something what looks like configuration file to visual HTML editor. Maybe one of you knows which HTML visual editor creates files with extension `*.html.add`.

For example near file `index.html` we got file `index.html.add` with following content:

```
<LASTEDITED BY="Przemek"/>
<OPTION NAME="WORDWRAP" STATE="ON"/>
<OPTION NAME="LINENUMBERS" STATE="ON"/>
<OPTION NAME="SHOWALLCHARS" STATE="OFF"/>
<OPTION NAME="DIVIDEEDITOR" STATE="SINGLE"/>
<OPTION NAME="WYSIWYGMODE" STATE="OFF"/>
<LIVESPELL ENABLED="ON"/>
<AUTOCORRECT ENABLED="ON"/>
<PARSER NAME="HTML+PHP extended"/>
<POSITION LINE="58" CHAR="0"/>
<SELECTION START="1020" LENGTH="0"/>
<SELECTIONNEW LEFT="1" TOP="65" RIGHT="1" BOTTOM="65" ISBLOCK="False"/>
```

Comment: Could this help? http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/add

Comment: May this article helps you :https://filext.com/file-extension/ADD#:~:text=If%20you%20cannot%20open%20your,with%22%20and%20choose%20an%20application. and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45669137/how-to-create-a-database-for-advantage-database-serverads

Answer (score 2):

I searched for "LIVESPELL ENABLED" which led me to http://www.trichview.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=1270 which mentions Addict 3.

> Addict is a component suite providing end-to-end solutions for adding spelling check and thesaurus support to your Delphi and C++Builder applications.

http://www.addictivesoftware.com/3rdparty.htm lists several HTML editors that can be used with this spell-check module, so I don't know if we can determine with any certainty which one was used for editing the files.

Also, note that searching for DIVIDEEDITOR and WYSIWYGMODE shows lots of similar results as what you have above.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Just in case it's not obvious, I'm pretty sure it's this - "Addict" -> .add file extension. :)